# Jackson ObjectMapper convert String to object that have inheritance

Tags: java, jackson

I have some classes that look likes this:

```
@Data
@ToString
class Parent {
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Data
@ToString
class Child {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@ToString
class SubChild extends Child {
    private String subName;
}
```

Now I have a JSON that look like this:

```
String json = "{" +
        "  \"children\": [" +
        "    {" +
        "      \"name\": \"some name\"," +
        "      \"subName\": \"some subName\"" +
        "    }" +
        "  ]" +
        "}";
```

I try to convert my String to an Object Parent like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Parent parent = objectMapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
```

But I got:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "subName" (class com.company.Child), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "name"])
 at [Source: (String)"{  "children": [    {      "name": "some name",      "subName": "some subName"    }  ]}"; line: 1, column: 66] (through reference chain: com.company.Parent["children"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.company.Child["subName"])

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
```

But If I change:

```
private List<Child> children;
```

To:

```
private List<SubChild> children;
```

everything works well, but in my case, I can't change the model, and in future, we can have other classes that can inherit from Child.

Is there any configuration that I can make to ObjectMapper to accept inheritance?

Comment: If you want to distinguish between multiple subclasses the most suitable option is add a type field to the `children` elements in the json file, can you modify it ?

Answer (score 1):

actually exception tells whats wrong.
`subName` is not property of `Child` object, if your json have subname `objectMapper` trying to map it to your object but your object dont have field like `subname` so `objectMapper` throw excepiton.

you should configure `objectMapper` like below to ignore unknown properties

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Parent parent = objectMapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
```